# Android Layout Repeating Pattern

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm setting up an android app that will display data like this:

```
Line Name        X    GGGGRR
Another Name     Y    GGGRRR
...
Last Name        Z    GGRRRR
```

where the names and x, y, z numbers are `TextView`s and the Gs and Rs are `ImageView`s showing red and green circles.

What's the best way to lay this out? I think putting the list in a vertical `LinearLayout` makes sense.
I don't want to repeat a bunch of `LinearLayout`s containing `TextView`s and `ImageView`s in the `XML`, because I might need to adjust the number of entries dynamically. What's the best way to encapsulate these lines? Should I create a custom layout for it? Or would it be better to use a fragment for each line?

Comment: Use a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Create a custom adapter for a list/recycler view that provides your custom view (each line).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Adapter for List View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sholud use a custom layout with textviews and imageviews as you said and you can use ListView or RecycleView for the list.